# ASP.NET custom MembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider

I have a client server application. The client is an asp.net c# site and the server is simply a command line application in c#. I plan on using .NET remoting to access and expose information that is on the server application and preset it to the user viewing the client.

The server application has user objects that i want to use for authentication with the asp.net login controls etc.

I implemented created a custom class "MyMembershipProvider" which implements MembershipProvider but i'm getting very confused now. What do i do next?

i know i need to update the Web.config with a "membership" node but all the examples i've seen have a reference to a connection string, mine does not need a connection string as it will not be using a database etc.

Answer (score 1):

OK so i figured it out.

I don't need a connection string or anything. All i had to do was put:

```
<membership defaultProvider="Name of the class that you created that implements the MembershipProvider class">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add
      name="Name of the class that you created that implements the MembershipProvider clas"
      type="fully qualified name of the class that you created that implements the MembershipProvider class" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I finally realized that the  element above has to be inside the < system.web > element and that fixed it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you find this article useful.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/528/how-to-use-the-sample-read-only-xml-membership-and-role-providers-with-iis-70/

You need to better understand why web.config needs a certain configuration, as those database based providers have a reason to use connection strings in web.config. Then you know how to configure your provider (without a connection string as yours does not use database).